# Batch file that reads the created time of the file and moves it into a new folder named based on that time

Tags: csv, batch-file, command-line

Only a daily bases i get 50+ .csv file that drops in my folder every hourly and i need help to automate this. the problem is i create a new folder i.e Batch 1 and i go thru all the files that landed with the time range of 1am till the next and cut them out and paste it into that folder 'Batch 1'

this becomes stressfull and time consuming to do when there are alot of files to cut and paste :(

i need help on a batch code that can:

1.read the 'time created of the file' (just hourly no need for the min)

2.if the file was created within ( 00:00 - 00:59 ) then move that file into new folder and name it 'Batch 1'

3. repeat the above step but with a different time frame ( 01:00 - 01:59 ) then move that file into new folder and name it 'Batch 2'

4.and repeat again with a different time till - ( 23:00 - 23:59 )

i have manged to only get as far as just creating a new folder but stuck on how to go on about reading the files.

sorry first time asking a question on here:p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information you provided, this should move the files.
Test it on sample files first.

```
@echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.csv /b /a-d') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%b in ("%%~ta") do (
        md "Batch %%b" 2>nul
        move "%%a" "Batch %%b" >nul
    )
)
pause
```

**Initial debugging steps below:**

When you run this in the folder it will show the format of the date/time string which can be used to get the hour.  Each computer can have a differing format.

If you can show a sample of the screen output then a simplified solution could be created.

```
@echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.csv /b /a-d') do (
  echo %%~ta
)
pause
```

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%g in ("%%~ta") do echo %%g %%a` improvement (instead of simple `echo %%a`) should dissect files to groups of `00`, `01`, …, `23`  by hour(s) of last write…